# AJAX Post Request over VPN stripping request data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, vpn

I've got a web application that is hosted behind a company intranet. For any users that need remote access the current solution is for them to connect via VPN, and then use the internal site location.

The application PHP based, with a front-end built on AJAX requests that get information and pages from the PHP backend.

Within the internal network there are **zero** problems making requests, however with a connection through the VPN almost 80% of all AJAX requests fail.

**So here's whats happening,** the browser is making a correct call, and attaching all of the post data. The server is receiving the request, without the data, and then sending back a failure as it is required. I've tried just echoing the $_POST array and it is empty whenever it fails.

Any ideas as to what could be causing the stripping of just the post data enroute? The VPN provider is Microsoft TMG, and the site is hosted on IIS 8.5.

**Edit:** Here's some example code to give a better idea of what I'm seeing.

**JS:**

```
var submit = 'test';

$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data: submit,
        url:base_url+'ajax_get_data/',
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 8000,
        success: function(data) {   

            // Do soemthing
        },
        error: function(e){

            // Error
        }
    });
```

**PHP:**

```
public function ajax_get_data(){

    var_dump($_POST);
    return;
}
```

In this example, looking at the return data raw from the server, here's what the inspector shows:

```
array(0){

}
```

The server is not actually receiving the attached request data, but the client browser is reporting that it sent the correct request data.

Comment: $_POST would only be set for client->server. It's NOT involved in server->client responses, because it's a PHP construct and your clients aren't running PHP.

Comment: Have you tested the exact same request while on the internal network and on the VPN to verify that there are no issues? Perhaps users are doing different tasks while on the VPN than they do at their desks and that is causing the issue. I've seen this happen A LOT. The "80% of all AJAX requests fail" is why I'm suspect

Comment: @Mark The $_POST variable is empty when it needs to have data to be filtered.

Comment: @Steve Yes, the internal site functions perfectly with hundreds of users making thousands of requests each day. VPN the exact same requests fail to deliver the post info to the server, and since it's required to return the result it returns a failure.

Comment: It seems strange that the VPN itself would strip off packets of the request. Are VPN requests rerouted in any way? Redirecting without [P] in Apache for example would strip off the request body. I'm pretty much out of ideas if that doesn't do it.

Comment: @Steve The clients are going directly to the IP of the hosting server, but I think your correct in that the VPN is stripping packets of the request. Maybe there's something funky going on in the VPN setup, I'll check into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally was able to resolve this issue recently.

To add a bit of detail missing from the above post, that I only discovered later, the issue was specific to Apple Devices (iOS/OS X).

Looks like there must have been a bug sitting in the Apple OS' preventing the requests from making it all the way through. **Updating iOS to iOS 10 and OS X to macOS Sierra has resolved the issue completely.**